# Where to put common code in view controller View functions?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

In one of the controllers, every view has a fixed preprocessing. Is there a better way of doing this, instead of the below code; such that **SomeFunctionAsync** works without writing that line before **return View()** for all functions with **return View()** in this controller? I also have some ajax post functions.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> View1()
{
    await SomeFunctionAsync();
    return View();
}

public async Task<ActionResult> View2()
{
    await SomeFunctionAsync();
    return View();
}
```

In other words, at the end I want to be able to write the following with having the same effect

```
public async Task<ActionResult> View1()
{
    return View();
}

public async Task<ActionResult> View2()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Controllers have actions, not views. Besides, what are you asking? "Common code" typically means extracting to a method and calling that method. Are you asking where to store that code, or how to get rid of the call and why? Eg, you can create filters but these add complexity

Comment: I want to get rid of the call. Currently that function is a private function in my controller. And every function which return a view should call that.

Comment: Are you unaware that you can pass a view name to the result perhaps? A single action can be rendered using different views. Instead of calling your methods `View1`, `View2` you should have a single action that is actually an action, eg `Create` and return `return View("View1")` or `return View("View2")`

Answer (score 2):

If Action Filter as suggested by Varun doesnt suits you, you can try another way.

Create a parent View  of all the view. In the action method for your parent view. Call this Method SomeFunctionAsync(). Thus, parent view will be called for all of yours views and the required method will be executed

Answer (score 0):

You can create a base class for your controller, and have have each view in your code call a generic method.  I use `GetView` as a method name (or you could override the existing ones).

Like so:

```
public class MyControllerBase : Controller {

    public Task<ActionResult> GetView() {
        yourCommonMethod();
        return View();
    }

    public Task<ActionResult> GetView(string viewName) {
        yourCommonMethod();
        return View(viewName);
    }

    public Task<ActionResult> GetView(object model) {
        yourCommonMethod();
        return View(model);
    }


    public Task<ActionResult> GetView(string viewName, object model) {
        yourCommonMethod();
        return View(viewName, model);
    }

}
```

Then in your controller, inherit from that:

```
public class MyController : MyControllerBase {

    public async Task<ActionResult> View1()
    {
        return GetView();
    }

}
```

If the common method is the same for all controllers and has no controller-specific dependencies, it could be that simple.  However, you may want to look at using generics as well:

```
public class MyControllerBase<T> : Controller {
    // base class stuff here based on type T's interface
}


public class MyController : MyControllerBase<MyController> {
    // regular class here, sending MyController to the base
}
```

These are pretty much building blocks of OOP.  You may do well to get a book that covers the basics of OOP and work through this type of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

There are tow ways :

1. Use a single Action with different views like return View("View1") or retrun View("View2"), you can make if else conditions there so you will call your function at a single place.
2. If you want to go with your current procedure(not recommended) then you have to use Action Filter attribute and decorate it on Controller level then every action would execute your logic before execution of your Action